# Why i cant get each value i want to fetch in td using each function

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#box-table-a").each(function(){

        var temp2=$(this).find(".tool-id").html();

        $("#box-table-a span").qtip({

        content: {
        url: 'description-hover.php',
        data: { id: temp2 },
        method: 'post'
               },
        show: 'mouseover',
        hide: 'click'
        });

 });


});

<table id="box-table-a" class="tablesorter">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>

                                        <th scope="col" style="cursor:pointer;">B-House/Dorm Name</th>
                                        <th scope="col" style="cursor:pointer;">Address</th>
                                        <th scope="col" style="cursor:pointer;">Price Range</th>
                                        <th scope="col" style="cursor:pointer;">Date Added</th>
                                        <th scope="col" style="cursor:pointer;">Status</th>

                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                   <?php



                                   $q=mysql_query("select * from property");
                                        while( $f=mysql_fetch_array($q, MYSQL_ASSOC))
                                        {
                                        $p_id=$f["p_id"];

                                   echo"

                                        <tr>
                                            <td id='tool-table'><span class='tool-id'>".$p_id."</span>
                                            <span id='testid' style='cursor:pointer'>".$f['p_name']."</span></td>
                                            <td id='pretty'>".$f['address']."</td>
                                            <td>".$f['p_name']."</td>
                                            <td>".$f['payment_type']."</td>      
                                            <td>".$status."</td>       
                                        </tr>       


                                    ";

                                    }



                                    ?>
                                        </tbody>
</table>
```

The temp2 variable is suppose to get each value(p_id) of span, so i can display the description in a tooltip when i hover. but the display is always the same. whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$(".tool-id").each(function(){

    var temp2=$(this).html();

    $(this).siblings("span").qtip({  // whatever span you want to set - change here

    content: {
    url: 'description-hover.php',
    data: { id: temp2 },
    method: 'post'
           },
    show: 'mouseover',
    hide: 'click'
    });
});

// Added for follow up request :)

$(document).click(function()
{
   if($('#testid').is(':visible){
       $(this).hide();
   }
});
```

Comment: i dont get what you mean dude.. what should i put inside your comment? i dont get also what $(this).siblings("span") do. can you please explain more. thank you

Comment: $(this).siblings('span') finds the span in the same element-tree level as the span containing the class '.tool-id' and applies your .qtip to it.

Comment: hey. true north creative.. i dont know how you got that answer. i dont understand what you mean.. but i copied your code.. modified mine, and it worked!!! thanks so much man. ive been working this one for weeks.. waiting here in site for replies all day, and only your answer solved my problem.. thanks

Comment: @true north creative: just one more favor man. can you make the code to hide the tooltip whenever i hover another span and whenever i click outside/inside the tooltip. or press escape (if its possible). that code of mine only hides the tooltip whenever i click on the span again, so when i hover another element it shows 2 tooltips already.. it sucks. thanks

Comment: haha - happy to help man.  Basically, think of it as this... `$(".tool-id").each(function(){` finds each span with the class="tool-id" and then gets it's contents.  Then `$(this).siblings("span")` finds the other span in that td - hope this makes sense :)

Comment: the click to clear doesnt work. although ive added " ' " the missing quote from :visible. my last problem is when i hover a span. it shows the tooltip. but when i hover another span again. it shows another tooltip, which makes them 2 tooltips. i want the previous tooltip to hide when i hover another span. thanks again man

Comment: You can set a global variable and declare what the "active" tooltip is, and make sure that when one is hovered, that it hides any that are visible.  It's hard to troubleshoot a little blindly.  The other way you could do it, would be to set the id of the tooltip span (right now it's testid I think) to you id, so like `<span id='tip_" . $p_id. "' style='cursor:pointer'>` and reference that in your siblings statement `siblings('#tip'+temp2).qtip`..  something like that

Answer (score 0):

change $("#box-table-a")) to $("#box-table-a tr"))